# Is this incorrect and why? $ \frac{d}{dx}[\tan^{-1}(x^2) = \ln(y) + e^{\cos{x}}]$

Tags: calculus, notation

s this incorrect and why? $$ \frac{d}{dx}[tan^{-1}(x^2) = ln(y) + e^{\cos{x}}]$$

This is a question in a practice exam for using implicit differentiation. Given that the relation is not explicitly solved for $y$, it seems convenient to use this notation to mean "take the derivative of what is in the brackets". But, is it correct? I think if it is incorrect, it is an abuse of notation at best, but given the differentiation is a linear operator, I think it may be correct.

Comment: What is equal to what?

Comment: The question is why is not correct. The implies that the original poster does not know why it is not correct. Can you elaborate?

Comment: he's asking for implicit differentiation notation

Comment: Well, so can you define $y$ as a function of $x$ or vice versa @Zeta10?

Comment: It is a relation such that $y=y(x)$

Comment: Then it's OK you can apply differential operator on both the sides

Answer (score 1):

It is poor notation in my opinion - "differentiating" the equals sign doesn't make sense. It would be clearer and more correct to write:
$$\tan^{-1}\left(x^2\right)=\ln y+e^{\cos(x)}\implies\frac{d}{dx}\tan^{-1}\left(x^2\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\ln y+e^{\cos(x)}\right],$$
which emphasizes that you are applying the differential operator to both sides and actually makes sense as an equality.

Comment: I can appreciate that. If you were to pose the question, would you say, something like find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and then just list the relation?

Comment: On the other hand it's a rather good abuse of notations in the sense that it couldn't possibly be interpreted as anything else.

Comment: @Zeta10 Yes, that is likely what I would do. The procedure to solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ would then be to differentiate both sides, as above, and use the chain rule. The method is fine, the only issue is the notation.

Comment: Why the downvote?